# Can't seem to get get SQL database to set Spinner correctly

Tags: android, sql, database, spinner

Problem is exactly as described. I am using a SQL db to save two strings and an int. The int is the spinner position. It seems to save and update just fine but when i return to the page to view it, it resets the spinner. I know it is saving the right position as I have my listview displaying the position saved.

{*Side note (Possibly unimportant)Interestingly changing one specific line of code changes what the spinner resets to. If i use the method

```
     trket.setSelection(codeIndex);
```

It sets the spinner at position 3

However if i use the code

```
trket.setId(codeIndex);
```

It sets the spinner at position 0}

Now for my code.

This first class is where you View/Edit/Save/Delete entries
Theres lots of extra code. Sorry. It's trimed as much as i could make it.

```
public class TestEdit extends Activity implements OnClickListener,OnItemSelectedListener{

 private long rowID; 
 private EditText caret,lapet;
 private Spinner trket;
 String a,b,c,message,pps,tys,rh1s,rh2s,sr1s,sr2s,de1s,de2s,dc1s,dc2s,ar1s,ar2s,c1s,c2s,t1s,t2s,bb1s,bb2s,li1s,li2s,la1s,la2s,lb1s,lb2s,df1s,df2s,g1s,g2s,g3s,g4s,g5s,g6s,g7s,gfs,tss,hps,tqs,lbs,mils,rpms,partss,commentss;
 String[] paths = { "six","five", "four", "three", "two", "one"};
 Button paste,sa,sh,cb;
 int position;


   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 


   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
      setContentView(R.layout.test_tunepage);
      caret = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
      lapet = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
      trket = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);


       sa = (Button)findViewById(R.id.delete);

        sa.setOnClickListener(this);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, paths
                );
        trket.setAdapter(adapter);
        trket.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);





       Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 


              if (extras != null)
      {
         rowID = extras.getLong("row_id");
         caret.setText(extras.getString("car"));  
         lapet.setText(extras.getString("lap"));  
         trket.setSelection(position);


         }

      Button saveButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
      saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
          {
              if (caret.getText().length() != 0)
                 {
                    AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> saveContactTask = 
                       new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>() 
                       {
                          @Override
                          protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) 
                          {
                             saveContact();
                             return null;
                          }

                          @Override
                          protected void onPostExecute(Object result) 
                          {
                             finish();
                          }
                       }; 

                    saveContactTask.execute((Object[]) null); 
                 }

                 else
                 {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(TestEdit.this);
                    alert.setTitle(R.string.errorTitle); 
                    alert.setMessage(R.string.errorMessage);
                    alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.errorButton, null); 
                    alert.show();
                 }
              } 
         });
       }
   private void deleteContact()
   {

      AlertDialog.Builder alertt = new AlertDialog.Builder(TestEdit.this);

      alertt.setTitle(R.string.confirmTitle); 
      alertt.setMessage(R.string.confirmMessage); 

      alertt.setPositiveButton(R.string.delete_btn,
         new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
         {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int button)
            {
               final TestDbCon dbConnector = 
                  new TestDbCon(TestEdit.this);

               AsyncTask<Long, Object, Object> deleteTask =
                  new AsyncTask<Long, Object, Object>()
                  {
                     @Override
                     protected Object doInBackground(Long... params)
                     {
                        dbConnector.deleteContact(params[0]); 
                        return null;
                     } 

                     @Override
                     protected void onPostExecute(Object result)
                     {
                        finish(); 
                     }
                  };

               deleteTask.execute(new Long[] { rowID });               
            }
         }
      );
      alertt.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel_btn, null).show();

   }

   @Override
   protected void onResume()
   {
      super.onResume();
      new LoadContacts().execute(rowID);
   } 

   private class LoadContacts extends AsyncTask<Long, Object, Cursor> 
   {
      TestDbCon dbConnector = new TestDbCon(TestEdit.this);

      @Override
      protected Cursor doInBackground(Long... params)
      {
         try {
            dbConnector.open();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         return dbConnector.getOneContact(params[0]);
      } 

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result)
      {
         super.onPostExecute(result);
         if (result != null && result.moveToFirst()) {

         // get the column index for each data item
         int nameIndex = result.getColumnIndex("car");
         int capIndex = result.getColumnIndex("lap");
         int codeIndex = result.getColumnIndex("trk");




         lapet.setText(result.getString(capIndex));
         //trket.setId(codeIndex);
         trket.setSelection(codeIndex);

         caret.setText(result.getString(nameIndex));
         }

         result.close();
         dbConnector.close();
      }
   } 

    private void saveContact() 
       {
          TestDbCon dbConnector = new TestDbCon(this);

          if (getIntent().getExtras() == null)
          {
              dbConnector.insertContact(
                      caret.getText().toString(),//1
                      lapet.getText().toString(),
                      trket.getLastVisiblePosition());

          }
          else
          {
             dbConnector.updateContact(rowID,
                caret.getText().toString(),
                lapet.getText().toString(), 
                trket.getLastVisiblePosition());

   }


   }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){

         case R.id.delete:
                deleteContact();
                break;}


          }



    private void getstrings() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        a=caret.getText().toString();
        b=lapet.getText().toString();

    }
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        position = trket.getSelectedItemPosition();

    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

}

I do believe this is the only important class, but if theres something else you may want to see just let me know. I'll be checking back here all the time.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

inside `saveContact` method

replace

```
trket.getLastVisiblePosition());
```

with

```
trket.getSelectedItemPosition();
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! Nothing changes once I change that code. It resets still

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to Rob Myers from Google+ who helped me figure out that i wasn't getting the result and setting the int correctly. Where i was setting the fields upon reentry into the activity i was calling

```
 trket.setSelection(codeIndex);
```

when i needed to be calling

```
 trket.setSelection(result.getInt(codeIndex));
```